# How to make Vim format C++ code automatically as I type

Tags: c++, vim, formatting, clang

I have setup `clang-format` to reformat the current line/selection when I press Ctrl-K in Vim (see the [official documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#vim-integration) how to do that). However, it's annoying to be constantly pressing Ctrl-K whenever I edit a line.

Is there a way to make Vim call `clang-format` as I type or edit code automatically, without me having to press Ctrl-K? In other words, probably after each key stroke in insert mode?

I haven't seen anybody setup vim this way --- what are the potential problems with this setup?

Comment: Running a shell script after every key probably won't be fast enough, but you can do it with the `CursorMovedI` autocmd... You might be able to map it to `<Cr>`  in insert mode, though. Of course, the best solution is learning how to type things correctly, which strikes me as a lot easier ...

Comment: Thank you. I see -- learn the style, and occasionally if I need help from clang-format, I can always press Ctrl-K manually.